# When pressed ctrl+c only break out of current function and not whole bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

I'm trying to write a script wherein if someone pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Keyboard interruption) then it shouldn't exit the entire script, just the current execution function.

Can anyone suggest what logic can I use here? Here is some sample code for the same

```sh
#!/bin/bash

func1()
{
wget https://example.com/test1.txt
cat text1.txt |awk '{print $3}'|tr -d '.' > temp1.txt
}

func2()
{
cat temp1.txt|<stdin-to-some-tool> > temp2.txt
}

func3()
{
<some-tool> temp2.txt > temp3.txt
}
```

Likewise, other functions should still execute in case we stop the function before that.

Comment: I think you might be able to put the functions in separate scripts. At that point, Ctrl-C might just exit the other script and return to the top-level file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Analysis

When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, the line discipline of your terminal sends `SIGINT` to processes in the foreground process group.

Bash, when job control is disabled, runs everything in the same process group as the `bash` process itself. Job control is disabled by default when Bash interprets a script. This means if a script runs in the foreground then the shell interpreting the script along with everything invoked by the script will belong to the foreground process group<sup>1</sup> and will receive `SIGINT` upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

You can enable job control on demand by `set -m`. When job control is enabled, Bash runs commands in separate process groups and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> gets to the group being the foreground process group at the moment.

This leads to two basic approaches in solving your problem.

---

#### Solution with `trap`s

This solution works without job control. Job control is disabled by default when Bash interprets a script, so no explicit configuration of the shell is required.

A process may ignore `SIGINT`. If it does then its children will ignore `SIGINT` as well<sup>2</sup>. Even if the shell interpreting the script does not ignore `SIGINT`, it may make some of its children ignore it<sup>3</sup>.

You want the main shell to ignore `SIGINT`. You want it to do this:

```
trap '' INT
```

At the same time you want your functions not to ignore `SIGINT`. You want them to do this:

```
trap - INT
```

To do this properly you need to use subshells. A function defined with `foo () { … }` and executed as `foo` runs as a part of the main shell, so `trap … INT` inside the function will affect the main shell. Such function can be run in a subshell on demand (e.g. as `(foo)` or in a pipeline) and then its trap will not affect the main shell. A function defined with `foo () ( … )` will always run in a subshell. For what you want to do it's good to define functions this way<sup>4</sup>.

Proof of concept:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap '' INT

foo () (
   trap - INT
   echo 'foo starts'
   sleep 5
   echo 'foo returns'
)

foo
echo 'main shell here'
foo
echo 'main shell exits'
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will interrupt `sleep` and the function (you won't see `foo returns`), but not the main shell.

Note any command you directly run from the main part of the script (i.e. not from the function) will inherit its setting to ignore `SIGINT`. To run a command that doesn't ignore it, you don't necessarily need a function, a subshell is enough. Example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap '' INT

sleep 5                     # immune to ctrl+c
echo 'try now'
(trap - INT; exec sleep 5)  # susceptible to ctrl+c
```

Similarly you can run a command immune to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> from inside a function susceptible to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in a script immune to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. It's all about what `trap` you invoke in what (sub)shell.

---

#### <strike>Solution with job control</strike>

(Removed. No longer works. I think it used to work. Under investigation.)

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Except when some process deliberately [leaves the group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462191/108618).

<sup>2</sup> Except when some child process deliberately chooses not to ignore.

<sup>3</sup> E.g. [asynchronous processes started in a script ignore `SIGINT`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/652145/108618). This way they don't react to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> despite being in the foreground process group. For comparison: in an interactive Bash (where job control is enabled by default) anything started in the background (i.e. with terminating `&`) does not react to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> because it doesn't get `SIGINT` in the first place. It doesn't get `SIGINT` because it's in a separate process group which is not the foreground process group. But when you `fg` it, its group becomes the foreground process group. When in the foreground, it can react to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

<sup>4</sup> However if you want the function to affect the main shell in other aspects (e.g. to modify variables of the main shell) then it must not run in a subshell. The requirements may turn out to be contradictory.

Comment: Could you provide zsh version of our solution 2?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Please can you clarify one doubt of mine? I tried to work out the second solution you gave, using job control (`set -m` in the script itself), but when I press ctrl+c, the entire script seems to stop working. I am using bash on Linux kernel 5.15.0-56-generic, `abhishek@abhishek:~$ ./test.sh
foo starts
^Cabhishek@abhishek:~$ ./test.sh
foo starts
foo returns
main shell here
foo starts
^Cabhishek@abhishek:~$ 
`

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh Thank your for bringing this to my attention. Either this solution was wrong from the start, or something has changed. I suspect the latter, since I tend to test my code quite thoroughly; but I cannot be sure.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for reverting back...

Answer (score 0):

To force the script to stop when Ctrl+c is send add the following lines at the beginning:

```
sigterm_handler() { 
  echo "Shutdown signal received."
  exit 1
}

## Setup signal trap
trap 'trap " " SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP; kill 0; wait; sigterm_handler' SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP
```