# Bash script to catch ctrl+c at higher level WITHOUT interrupting the foreground task

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script where I can execute a command `tail -F /tmp/foo.txt |& grep -E "error"`.

I want to be able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> the running script and using a trap or some other mechanism to intercept the SIGINT signal inside the script *without* disturbing the command.

I have investigated the trap and job control examples described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1653229/when-pressed-ctrlc-only-break-out-of-current-function-and-not-whole-bash-script/1653310#1653310?newreg=b21b42d0ea9c4efe8aaf6d2fdebfb476) and in fact this example says

> Similarly you can run a command immune to Ctrl+c from inside a
> function susceptible to Ctrl+c in a script immune to Ctrl+c. It's all
> about what trap you invoke in what (sub)shell.

However I have not been able to get this to work in practice.  If I make a command immune to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then I never receive the SIGINT at the higher level of bash.

Here is an example with a sleep call which seems to indicate that things do (kinda) work but not as expected

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "trap worked"' INT

(
   trap '' INT
   sleep 5
   echo "done"
)
```

The result is:

```
^Cdone
trap worked
```

So in this case the `sleep` call has to finish and then the trap gets invoked after the subshell is done.  If I were to replace the `sleep` call with the `tail`/`grep` line then the subshell will never exit since SIGINT is blocked and the higher level bash doesn't seem to get the SIGINT until after the subshell is done.

How do I go about doing this in bash?  I'm not married to using traps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387854/108618) explains why you see `trap worked` only after `done`. If you run the subshell in the background and then `wait` for it, the result will be different:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "trap worked"' INT

(
   trap '' INT
   sleep 5
   echo "done"
) &

wait
```

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> when the subshell works, it will trigger the trap immediately. It will also make the script go past `wait` and thus finish. Run `wait` in a loop if you don't want the script to finish:

```bsh
until wait; do :; done
```

This way you will be able to trigger the trap multiple times easily and the script will exit after the subshell exits.

I guess this is not exactly what you mean by "without interrupting the foreground task", since the task (here: `sleep`) is in the background instead and it has its consequences. When job control is disabled (and it is by default in a script), `&` redirects stdin to `/dev/null` or equivalent file. This way what you run in the background cannot steal input. If you want our background subshell to be able to read from the stdin of the whole script then you need to explicitly redirect stdin to stdin (`<&0`). It looks like a no-op, but with `&` it actually makes sense, it makes an asynchronous job behave more like a job in the foreground:

```bsh
(…) <&0 &
```

Another thing: note `wait` without arguments waits for all currently active child processes. If your actual script runs more jobs in the background and you want `wait` not to wait for some of them, the easiest way may be to `disown`.

---

Example code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "trap worked"' INT

(
   trap '' INT
   sleep 10
   echo "(not waited for) done"
) &
disown "$!"

(
   trap '' INT
   cat
   echo "(waited for) done"
) <&0 &

until wait; do :; done
```

Notes:

- `cat` and `sleep` are both immune to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.
- You can strike <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and trigger the trap multiple times.
- At the same time you can write lines to `cat` and it will work, i.e. it will print upon <kbd>Enter</kbd> (but if you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in the middle of a line then what you typed so far (i.e. what hasn't been delivered to `cat` yet) will be discarded and never delivered to `cat` because this is how the line discipline works).
- Exit `cat` [with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/701317/108618) before `sleep 10` finishes and you will see the script does not wait for the disowned job.

---

Side note: while playing with SIGINT and bash, it's good to know bash implements a "wait and cooperative exit" approach at handling SIGINT/SIGQUIT delivery. See [this link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#Special_Note_On_SIGINT_and_SIGQUIT) and [this article](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html).

Comment: Thanks launching the subshell in the background and using wait worked for me.  I didn't know about disown good tip.  Thanks for your thoughtful answer